# installing error of vmd in ubuntu 14.04 lts(./configure ..error)

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, compiling, configure

during installing vmd-1.9.2 after giving the command

./configure Makefile

The following error shows, what to do ?

```
a@a-PP-990:~/Downloads/vmd-1.9.2$ ./configure Makefile  
Architecture Makefile not supported (IRIX6 IRIX6_64 FREEBSD FREEBSDAMD64 HPUX11 AIX4 AIX5 AIX5_64 AIX6_64 ANDROIDARMV7A BLUEGENEQ BLUEWATERS LINUX LINUXALPHA LINUXAMD64 LINUXIA64 LINUXCARMA LINUXPPC LINUXPPC64 MACOSX MACOSXX86 MACOSXX86_64 TRU64 SOLARIS2 SOLARIS2_64 SOLARISX86 SOLARISX86_64 WIN32 WIN64)
```

I am installing vmd 64 bit.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the build process from the `~/Downloads/vmd-1.9.2/` folder should be:

1. `./configure`
2. `make`
3. `sudo make install`

I am not familiar with `vmd` at all to know if it is possible to run on your system, but those are the steps that I have followed on the majority of installs from source.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.yes thats fine..but why './configure Makefile' giving thats output??Is it any problem of vmd or my system?

Comment: @atanu The command is just `./configure` by itself.  The Makefile is used for the `make` and `make install` commands.

Comment: @atanu Here is a better overview of what Makefiles do:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31488/Makefiles-in-Linux-An-Overview

Comment: Or `sudo checkinstall` :)